# Почему forEach добавляет текст ко всем элементам массива, а добавление элемента происходит один раз

Tags: javascript, foreach

```js
const list = document.querySelector('.list');
const listItems = list.querySelectorAll('.list__item');
const simpleText = 'Text';
const simpleEl = document.createElement('span');

listItems.forEach(item => {
  item.innerText = simpleText;
  item.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', simpleEl);
});
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item"></li>
  <li class="list__item"></li>
  <li class="list__item"></li>
  <li class="list__item"></li>
</ul>
```

Result:

```
<ul class="list">
        <li class="list__item">Text</li>
        <li class="list__item">Text</li>
        <li class="list__item">Text</li>
        <li class="list__item">Text<span></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Потому что нужно разные элементы добавлять, а не один и тот же. Это как яблоко положить одновременно в 4 тарелки

Comment: Потому что создаётся элемент один раз и один и тот же элемент по очереди вставляется во все ЛИ. Создавай спан внутри цикла..

Answer (score 0):

Как я уже упомянул в комментариях, ваша ошибка в том, что вы пытаетесь запихнуть один и тот же спан одновременно в 4 элемента. Поэтому вам нужно либо клонировать исходный span и копию добавлять к содержимому li, либо каждый раз создавать новый span.

Пример:

```js
const list = document.querySelector('.list');
const listItems = list.querySelectorAll('.list__item');
const simpleText = 'Text';

listItems.forEach(item => {
  item.innerText = simpleText;
  let simpleEl = document.createElement('span'); // каждый раз создаем новый спан, его и добавляем в li
  item.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', simpleEl);
});
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item"></li>
  <li class="list__item"></li>
  <li class="list__item"></li>
  <li class="list__item"></li>
</ul>
```